# Regular expression to only accept Alphabets with semicolon seperated

Tags: regex

Looking for regex which accepts only Alphabets(A-Z) with semicolon separated.
below are the examples which should be accepted by Regex and anything else if contains should not be accepted at all.

Examples:

```
A
A;B
A;B;C;F
A;E;Q
A;YY
```

I tried this:

```
[A-Z]+(;[A-Z]+)*$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: This is a really simple regular expression, I guess you need to read a tutorial like www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: I know it looks simple but I tried below options which are not working  [A-Z]+(;[A-Z]+)*$  and   [a-zA-Z;]+$

Comment: `[help-me]` You've provided the expected behavior and the regexp. This is a good start. Please provide the observed behavior and how it differs from the expected behavior.

Comment: I'm using below regex in MDS in a business rule to allow only alphabets with semicolon separated or should allow Not Applicable to be entered. but when I enter Not Applicable the regex is failing and not accepting that value. Any idea on if its different in MDS as I am testing the regex in http://regexstorm.net/tester its working fine.    ^([A-Za-z]+(;[A-Za-z]+)*$)|(Not Applicable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct, you forgot the `^` anchor to make it start at the beginning of the input:

```
^[A-Z]+(;[A-Z]+)*$
```